# Undefined Attributes Task_ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I think I am missing something because of the following code bellow, I have included the error message, what I think is that tasks table doesn't have a task_id, but when I ran a migration to add task_id to tasks, it still gave me this error.

**Routes**

```
   resources :tasks do
       resources :comment
   end
```

**Model - comments**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :author, :comment
  belongs_to :tasks
  has_one :author
  validates :comment, :presence => true
end
```

**Model Tasks**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :task
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

**Comments Controller**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @comment = Comment.new
    @comments = Comment.all
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @task.Comment.create(params[:task])
    redirect_to post_path(@task)
  end

end
```

**the form - partial**

```
<%= form_for ([@task, @task.comments.build]) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Whats the issue?**

```
unknown attribute: task_id

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for ([@task, @task.comments.build]) do |f| %>
2:  <%= f.text_area :comment %>
3:  <%= f.submit %>
4: <% end %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/tasks/show.html.erb

Rails.root: /home/adam/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/StartPoint
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/forms/_comments.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_forms__comments_html_erb___445541804__622889658'
app/views/tasks/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_tasks_show_html_erb___428009053_87363420'

Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"3"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what I am think is that tasks table doesn't have a task_id, but when I rad a migration to add task_id to tasks, it still gave me this error

You're thinking about the wrong table. When you say this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :task # Note that this should be singular as zeacuss notes below
end
```

ActiveRecord assumes that the `comments` table will have a `task_id` column to link back to the `tasks` table. You don't need a migration to add `tasks.task_id`, you need a migration to add `comments.task_id`.

The [ActiveRecord Associations Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association) might make some good reading.

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :task
end
```

`task` not `tasks` as it is a one to one correspondence.

read more about belongs_to association here:

[belongs_to](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs_to-association)